# line integral along a curve

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $ \varphi(x,y) = x^3y+xy^3 ((x,y) \in R^")$, and let $C$ the curve given by $\varphi(x,y)=5$

The question is, how can I calculate the line integral of $\bigtriangledown\varphi$ along the curve $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are on a curve of constant value, so the gradient's component along this line iz zero.

Comment: so the integral is zero and thats it? It doesnt matter if we have $\varphi (x,y) = x^3y+xy^3$?

Comment: Exactly. The integral would evaluate to the "height difference" between initial and final point, but you stayed at the same height, so the difference is zero.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int\pars{\partiald{\varphi}{x}\,\dd x + \partiald{\varphi}{y}\,\dd y}}
&=
\int\pars{\partiald{\varphi}{x} + \partiald{\varphi}{y}\,y'}\dd x
=\int\bracks{\partiald{\varphi}{x} + \partiald{\varphi}{y}\,
\pars{-\,{\partial\varphi/\partial x \over \partial\varphi/\partial y}}}\dd x
=\color{#00f}{\Large 0}
\end{align}